# Don't include lodash in production build, but use it when single file is imported

Tags: javascript

I'm writing my own JS library of helpers that I need in my projects.

https://github.com/kitze/kitze-js-helpers

In the projects where I'm using ES6 and Babel I just want to import some of the helpers like

```js
import {getPropertyFromAnotherArray} from 'kitze-js-helpers/src/helpers/array-helpers';
```

But I'm getting this error `array-helpers.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: _lodash2.default.map is not a function`

In the package.json of my library I have this:

```
    "browser": {
        "lodash": false,
        "atob": false,
        "btoa": false
    },
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [
        "babelify",
        "browserify-shim"
    ]
    },
    "browserify-shim": {
        "lodash": "global:_"
    }
```

The error goes away if I remove those properties from package.json, but then lodash, atob, and btoa will get bundled along with my helpers in the dist/ folder.

At the top of [array-helpers.js](https://github.com/kitze/kitze-js-helpers/blob/master/src/helpers/array-helpers.js) I have

```js
    import _ from 'lodash'
```

So the behaviour that I want is:

- If the library is used as a [bundled/minified](https://github.com/kitze/kitze-js-helpers/tree/master/dist) version I would
  like lodash not to be bundled inside with the helpers, but to be used
  from window._ , so lodash must be included with a 
  before the helpers.
- If the library is used in ES6 environment and only one file is
  included, lodash should be used from the node_modules folder of the current project where the helpers are included.
- When building a bundled/minified version of the library lodash should  be ignored and not included in [the final build](https://github.com/kitze/kitze-js-helpers/blob/master/dist/kitze-js-helpers.js).

Any help?